# Calculating area of convex figures from given vertices in Scala

Tags: scala

I have been given a set of vertices, which can vary from 3 to 20, and I need to implement a generic method to calculate the area of the polygon defined by those vertices [This vertices are placed in a 2D plane and the defined polygon is not self-intersecting]

The polygon vertices are give as:

```
N      //Num sides Polygon
x1 y1
x2 y2
x3 y3
...
xn yn
```

With that in mind what I was planning to do is to polygon [triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation):

Where I pick one initial vertex and then split the rest of the polygon into triangles (fan triangulation), like this:

[image]

The area of a irregular triangle can be calculated like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-find-area-triangle/):

```
val s : Double = (a+b+c)/2; 
val area : Double = Math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
```

So I wrote the following code to calculate the area following this approach:

```
case class Point(val x: Double, val y: Double)
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

// Method to calculate length of side between to vertices
def distance(ori: Point, des: Point): Double = {
    Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ori.x - des.x, 2) + Math.pow(ori.y - des.y, 2))
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Number of sides in the Polynom
    val sidesPoly = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().toInt
    var listPoints = new ListBuffer[Point]()

    // ListBuffer with the input sides
    for(i <- 1 to sidesPoly){
        val tuple = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().split(" ")
        val newPoint = new Point(tuple(0).toDouble, tuple(1).toDouble)
        listPoints += newPoint
    }

    // Iterating list in Fan mode to split the polygon into triangles
    var area : Double = 0
    for(i <- 1 to listPoints.size-2){
        var triangle = new ListBuffer[Point]()
        //We divide the polygon into triangles
        val side1 = distance(listPoints(0),listPoints(i))
        val side2 = distance(listPoints(i),listPoints(i+1))
        val side3 = distance(listPoints(i+1),listPoints(0))
        // Calculating the area of the triangle
        val s = (side1+side2+side3)/2
        val triangleArea = Math.sqrt(s*(s-side1)*(s-side2)*(s-side3))
        // Adding the area of the triangle to the total Polygon Area
        area += triangleArea
    }
    println(area)
}
```

The problem I faced is the method doesn't work with [concave](https://www.mathopenref.com/polygonconcave.html) polygons.

Does anyone know a better approach than Fan Triangulation for concave polygons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this [approach](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/area-irregular-polygons.html) which works for both, concave and convex:

```
case class Point(val x: Double, val y: Double)
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

// Method to calculate the Area under each side of the polygon
def calculateAreaUnderSegment(A: Point , B: Point): Double = {
    val averHeight = (A.y + B.y)/2
    val width = (A.x - B.x)
    width * averHeight
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Numer of sides Polygon
    val sidesPoly = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().toInt

    //List of Vertices Polygon
    var listPoints = new ListBuffer[Point]()
    for(i <- 1 to sidesPoly){
        val tuple = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().split(" ")
        val newPoint = new Point(tuple(0).toDouble, tuple(1).toDouble)
        listPoints += newPoint
    }

    // Iterating over each pair of vertex
    var area : Double = 0
    for(i <- 0 to listPoints.size-2){
        area += calculateAreaUnderSegment(listPoints(i),listPoints(i+1))
    }

    // For the last segment (to come back to the original vertex)
    area += calculateAreaUnderSegment(listPoints(listPoints.size-1),listPoints(0))
    println(area)
}
```